# Movement during prayer

Tags: salat

While I am going for sijdah what if I notice a piece of glass or any obstacle
Can I remove it by my hand before my forehead touches the ground quickly ? What to do if I notice it while in sitting position
Or in between two sijdah the object comes at the place of sijdah suddenly?
What if it requires leaning a little bit  to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

If it hinders your prayer, or may cause you an injury, you may move it. However, you cannot turn around and put it aside, you must either throw it aside or bruh it away.